"CreateWithURL err=1 (Operation not permitted)" when importing photos on macOS Sonoma
I copied several thousand photos off of a network drive onto my local drive and I'm trying to import them into Photos. Several hundred of them had an "Unknown Error" importing, so I opened Console, tried reimporting one of the failed photos, and found this in the logs:
CreateWithURL:306: *** ERROR: err=1 (Operation not permitted) - could not open /Users/david/Downloads/1980s/1989_April_0001_a.jpg

I'm stumped. I allowed Full Disk Access for Photos in the settings and restarted. I ran chmod 777 on all the photos. I even tried running Photos as sudo. I got the same error every time. I ran DiskUtil diagnostics on the drive and it's not showing any file permissions issues.
Some Googling tells me that this is due to the System Integrity Protection baked into the last few macOS releases, but I still don't understand why Photos wouldn't have the necessary permissions on these files. I'd also like to not disable SIP, but I'm not sure what else to do. Is there anything else I can try?

Have you tried opening those files any other way, such as Preview or just a Finder "Quick Look"?

Hey @Spiff, thanks for your response. I have, yeah. They open fine. The strange thing is, I made duplicates of them using the Quick Actions -> Convert Images, and those copies import fine. It makes me think there's some property of the images that SIP is tracking but that's not visible to me.

Also if relevant, I got these off the network drive with a terminal command, but I'm dragging and dropping them into Photos from Finder.

Actually, edit, I tried the Convert Images with a second batch of photos and that didn't work. So I'm not sure what's happening here.

See if stripping extended attributes works - https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/416592/85275

Thanks @Tetsujin. I tried that and it's still erroring. Good idea, though. I wasn't aware there was another set of attributes files could have that were macOS-specific, but I'd guessed there was something like that going on under the hood based on the behavior.

So I just saw some strange behavior. I had a photo that was flagged as not importing due that error. I closed Photos. I moved the file to a different folder. I opened Photos. I imported that photo and it worked. Is there some kind of permissions caching happening that changes when I touch a file?

Oh. Actually, just closing and opening Photos again is enough to import the photo individually. Maybe there is some caching happening in Photos?
